# How to re-create .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, rhel8

I accidently deleted .bashrc from my user. Is there any way to create it again.

I used command touch .bashrc to create the file again and also given the required data inside the file. But it is not working.

Can anyone tell me how to recreate the file?

Comment: The normal way would be to pull in a backup. You mention rhel8, so are you on a school or business computer? If so, check with admin how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, It is RHEL8 on business computer.

Comment: That's good news then. Your IT guys will know how to get it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RHEL, you can find the default content of a home directory in `/etc/skel`:

```bash
$ ls -la /etc/skel
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   78 Mar 29 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 149 root root 8192 May 25 11:24 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   18 Jun 20  2022 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  141 Jun 20  2022 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  376 Jun 20  2022 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root   39 Mar 29 17:07 .mozilla
```

Comment: Hey, how can I pull the file from /etc/skel into my user?

Comment: @Rudra `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~` - but that won't get any changes you made to your original back.